# How do I use FILTER_CALLBACK with filter_input_array and use a class method with arguments that are not invoked in the constructor?

Tags: php, filter, callback

I have this,

```
    $validate = new Validate();
    $filters = array (
        'customer-last-name' => array (
            'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
            'options'=> array($validate, 'validateLength("johnny")')
        )
    );
```

*Warning: filter_input_array(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback*

I have seen many questions and answers of SO for this, but of the ones I have found, none of them have a way to call a method and pass the parameters to the method.  They usually either have them in the same class and use $this or they put all arguments in the constructor so they can call the method like:

```
'options'=> array($validate, 'validateLength')
```

That works fine, but that is not what I am trying to do.

I also do not wish to use a closure, anonymous function, or the like.  I know that if I do not put any arguments then function sends my form value.  I just need to add arguments with it.  The questions are too many to list to show I have searched.

This works:

```
public function validateLength($value, $min=1, $max=2){
    return $value;
}
```

when I do the options like `array($validate, 'validateLength');`

Can it be done without creating the object with values sent to the constructor?

Comment: The callback function is only ever passed a single value, the value to be validated.  Why not use an object, or closure?

Comment: I supposed if in my closure I call another method I am not a tightly coupled.  I do use an object.  I cannot call a method on that object, so maybe I don't understand what you mean.